# Problem about CPLEX Error 32201 License invalid

Tags: cplex

I have a problem running my program CPLEX STUDION 12.6 (32b) "CPLEX Error 32201:License invalid" ,can you give me the solution of this error and thanks in advance .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROeCt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of information about this error at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21568759

> This error can only occur with versions 12.2 to 12.4 of CPLEX
>   Optimization Studio obtained through the IBM Academic Initiative
>   before May of 2012. Commercial licenses of CPLEX Optimization Studio
>   do not use the ILOG License Manager (ILM) that issues this type of
>   message. Starting in May 2012, Academic Initiative versions stopped
>   using license files altogether, and this issue can no longer happen.
>   If you have encountered this license error and remain eligible for an
>   academic licenses, we recommend that you renew your academic license
>   rather than try to resolve the license error. However, if you prefer
>   to resolve the license error, the following discussion will probably
>   help.

If you're an academic user, you may get a free version at https://ibm.onthehub.com/WebStore/ProductSearchOfferingList.aspx?srch=cplex